# Сортировка поля с цифрами в строке

Tags: sql

Такой запрос к бд

```
SELECT * FROM `pladform` WHERE `project_id` = 12387 ORDER BY title
```

при этом получаю список в таком порядке

> Султан Разия - 1 серия
>   Султан Разия - 10 серия
>   Султан Разия - 100 серия
>   Султан Разия - 101 серия
>   ...
>   Султан Разия - 11 серия
>   Султан Разия - 110 серия

Как можно отсортировать, чтобы серии были указаны по естественному порядку?

> 1
>   2
>   3...
>   10
>   11
>   ...
>   100
>   101

Comment: проблема в том, что такой порядок какой выдан и есть естественный для строк, т.е. библиографический. Единственный способ отсортировать в порядке номеров - привести строки к числу, в вашем случае как то из середины строк вытащить цифры. В таких случаях следует хранить номера серий в отдельном числовом поле

Comment: понял, спасибо!